# Disable creating sort index SELECT post_modified_gmt

Tags: theme-development, mysql, server, core

strangely my theme doesn't have the function that generates queries like this

```
SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') ORDER BY post_modified_gmt DESC LIMIT 1
```

however after I checked

```
mysql -e "show full processlist"
```

it has too many queries above

Is there any way to prevent this query from happening, it really overloads the website

Thank you very much